# python new dict if value matching key value inside dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I try to manipulate my data and I face some problem, I guess some of you will know how to do so.

First I arrange my data like this list of dict :

```
data = [{'compound' : 'molecule1', 'time' : 18, 'temp' : 20, 'orientation' : 'top', 'n' : 1, 'result' : 2.5} , {'compound' : 'molecule1', 'time' : 18, 'temp' : 20, 'orientation' : 'top', 'n' : 2, 'result' : 3.8}, {'compound' : 'molecule1', 'time' : 18, 'temp' : 20, 'orientation' : 'top', 'n' : 3, 'result' : 2.7}, {'compound' : 'molecule1', 'time' : 18, 'temp' : 20, 'orientation' : 'bottom', 'n' : 1, 'result' : 34.2} , {'compound' : 'molecule1', 'time' : 18, 'temp' : 20, 'orientation' : 'bottom', 'n' : 2, 'result' : 38.6}, {'compound' : 'molecule1', 'time' : 18, 'temp' : 20, 'orientation' : 'bottom', 'n' : 3, 'result' : 27.3}]
```

As you see, changing values are **orientation**, replicate number **n** and **result**.

I try to get this new arrangement :

```
arrangeData = [{'compound' : 'molecule1', 'time' : 18, 'temp' : 20, 'orientation' : 'top', n : [1,2,3], 'result' : [2.5, 3.8, 2.7]}, {'compound' : 'molecule1', 'time' : 18, 'temp' : 20, 'orientation' : 'bottom', n : [1,2,3], 'result' : [34.2, 38.6, 27.3]}]
```

As you may guess, my real data list of dict contain several **compound, time, temp**

My first stupid supposition was to loop over each element :

```
for d in data:
    if d[0] == 'molecule1':
        if d[1] == 18:
            if d[2] == 20
          ...
```

But it's hard coding and totaly unefficient.

Then, I trying to use list of each value :

```
compound = ['molecule1', 'molecule2', 'molecule3]
time = [18, 24]
temp = [20, 37]
orientation = ['top', 'bottom']
```

and loop again each list :

```
for d in data:
    for c in compound:
        for t in time: 
            for tp in temp:
                for o in orientation: 
                   if d[0] == c:
                   ...
```

Stupid as well, because all data are in my list of dict, so introducing a list of values seems to be a wrong way.

Here are questions :

1. Should I use another format to stock each conditions and result instead of a dict ?
2. How to check value of dict and create a new dict of data (like arrangeData mentioned above) ?

**EDIT 1**

Thanks Hai Vu that exactly what I looking for !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that for these rows of data, you want to group them by (compound, time, temp, and orientation). If that is not the case, you can make changes to my code below.

The idea is to create a temporary dictionary (out) whose keys are the values of (compound, time, temp, and orientation), and values are what you expected:

```
{('molecule1', 18, 20, 'bottom'): {'compound': 'molecule1',
                                   'n': [1, 2, 3],
                                   'orientation': 'bottom',
                                   'result': [34.2, 38.6, 27.3],
                                   'temp': 20,
                                   'time': 18},
 ('molecule1', 18, 20, 'top'): {'compound': 'molecule1',
                                'n': [1, 2, 3],
                                'orientation': 'top',
                                'result': [2.5, 3.8, 2.7],
                                'temp': 20,
                                'time': 18}}
```

Here is the code:

```
from pprint import pprint

data = [
    {'compound' : 'molecule1', 'time' : 18, 'temp' : 20, 'orientation' : 'top', 'n' : 1, 'result' : 2.5} ,
    {'compound' : 'molecule1', 'time' : 18, 'temp' : 20, 'orientation' : 'top', 'n' : 2, 'result' : 3.8},
    {'compound' : 'molecule1', 'time' : 18, 'temp' : 20, 'orientation' : 'top', 'n' : 3, 'result' : 2.7},
    {'compound' : 'molecule1', 'time' : 18, 'temp' : 20, 'orientation' : 'bottom', 'n' : 1, 'result' : 34.2} ,
    {'compound' : 'molecule1', 'time' : 18, 'temp' : 20, 'orientation' : 'bottom', 'n' : 2, 'result' : 38.6},
    {'compound' : 'molecule1', 'time' : 18, 'temp' : 20, 'orientation' : 'bottom', 'n' : 3, 'result' : 27.3}
]

out = {}
for row in data:
    # Group the data by these columns that are the same
    key = (row['compound'], row['time'], row['temp'], row['orientation'])

    # This is the first time we encounter this row of data, copy most
    # values over and create empty lists for the 'n' and 'result'
    # column
    if key not in out:
        out[key] = row.copy()
        out[key]['n'] = []
        out[key]['result'] = []

    # Now we can append the 'n' and 'result' columns
    out[key]['n'].append(row['n'])
    out[key]['result'].append(row['result'])

# After we are done, we can obtain the arranged data
arrangeData = out.values()
pprint(arrangeData)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can have only two different orientation value, this code will more than work.

But if you have too many variations, in that case, this is not a very good solution. I would rather make two list of dictionaries rather than two list of lists.

```
n_list = [[],[]]
result_list = [[],[]]

for i in data:
    if i['orientation'] == 'top':
        n_list[0].append(i['n'])
        result_list[0].append(i['result'])
    elif i['orientation'] == 'bottom':
        n_list[1].append(i['n'])
        result_list[1].append(i['result'])


for i in data:
    if i['orientation'] == 'top':
        i['n'] = n_list[0]
        i['result'] = result_list[0]
    elif i['orientation'] == 'top':
        i['n'] = n_list[1]
        i['result'] = result_list[1]


print data
```

A much shorter solution if you prefer:

```
n_list = {}
result_list = {}

for i in data:
    n_list.setdefault(i['orientation'], []).append(i['n'])
    result_list.setdefault(i['orientation'], []).append(i['result'])

for i in data:
    i['n'] = n_list[i['orientation']]
    i['result'] = result_list[i['orientation']]
```

Output:

```
[{
    'orientation': 'top',
    'temp': 20,
    'compound': 'molecule1',
    'n': [1, 2, 3],
    'result': [2.5, 3.8, 2.7],
    'time': 18
}, {
    'orientation': 'top',
    'temp': 20,
    'compound': 'molecule1',
    'n': [1, 2, 3],
    'result': [2.5, 3.8, 2.7],
    'time': 18
}, {
    'orientation': 'top',
    'temp': 20,
    'compound': 'molecule1',
    'n': [1, 2, 3],
    'result': [2.5, 3.8, 2.7],
    'time': 18
}, {
    'orientation': 'bottom',
    'temp': 20,
    'compound': 'molecule1',
    'n': 1,
    'result': 34.2,
    'time': 18
}, {
    'orientation': 'bottom',
    'temp': 20,
    'compound': 'molecule1',
    'n': 2,
    'result': 38.6,
    'time': 18
}, {
    'orientation': 'bottom',
    'temp': 20,
    'compound': 'molecule1',
    'n': 3,
    'result': 27.3,
    'time': 18
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `arrangeData` you give as example it seems like you want to group variables **n** and **result** for combination of **compound**, **time**, **temp** and **orientation**.

I'm not going to write code for you, but explain how I would do this. I would write two loops. The first creates a dictionary with as key the tuple (**compound**, **time**, **temp** and **orientation**), and as values **n** and **result** as growing lists. Then in a second loop I would transform that data structure into the list of dicts format of arrangeData.

It seems like this is part of a bigger codebase, maybe you can share a bit more of the context. There might be even a simpler solution to get to your goal.